# Unable to reach a settlement: issue

Tags: java, sftp, jsch, sshj

I'm trying to create jar for sftp. I use SSHJ (0.23.0) and everything is fine on test server, but the problem is when I try to run it on production server.

Java version on my production server is 7u60.

SSHJ Log:

```
net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException: **Unable to reach a settlement: [diffie-hellman-group1-sha1] and [curve25519-sha256@libssh.org, ecdh-sha2-nistp256, ecdh-sha2-nistp384, ecdh-sha2-nistp521, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256, diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]** at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Proposal.firstMatch(Proposal.java:165)      
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Proposal.negotiate(Proposal.java:147)
at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.KeyExchanger.gotKexInit(KeyExchanger.java:239)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.KeyExchanger.handle(KeyExchanger.java:364)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl.handle(TransportImpl.java:478)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.decode(Decoder.java:127)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.received(Decoder.java:195)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Reader.run(Reader.java:72)
```

[This is similar question, but this guy started using Jsch.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519462/net-schmizz-sshj-transport-transportexception-unable-to-reach-a-settlement)

Jsch (in my case 0.1.54, Java 7u60) also works fine on test server, but in production server it gives me following exceptions:

Jsch log:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.receive_kexinit(Session.java:520)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:286)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:150)
```

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that SSHJ is configured to only use the `diffie-hellman-group1-sha` key exchange algorithm, whereas your server supports a bunch of them, but not that one.

If you've not done that explicitly, the most likely reason is that you've either not loaded BouncyCastle, or the high-strength cryptography extensions are not loaded in your Java VM.